# 2 neutral wires to one connector

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm fitting a bathroom light which has live and neutral backstab connectors, both of which only accept a single wire. I need to connect two neutral wires though - the previous fitting had them both connected through a standard screw fitting.

Is there a standard way to handle this? If I connect the two neutrals using a three way connector along with another wire, and then connect that wire to the light, will it work or will I be burning down my house?

Comment: I would use a wirenut to bring them together with a stub that goes into the connector.  Have you considered that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the backstabs accept 14 AWG only?  Are the bathroom receptacles on the circuit?  You cannot use the lamp, bathroom receptacles must be 20A and 14 AWG wire is not legal on 20A circuits.  If it has screws, use them - backstabs are bad news anyway.

Ok, so get a 6 inch length of correct size Romex.  Strip it down for the hot, neutral and ground wire.  Use those to connect to the single terminal on the lamp.   This seems like it makes things worse because now you have 3 black wires and 3 white wires to connect instead of only 2.   Get **wire nuts** or other type of splice connector which accommodates 3 wires.

Comment: Sounds good - there are no outlets in the bathroom so should be good to use the lamp as is

Comment: @JimStewart [this](http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php/File:CeilingRoseInternal.gif) is the original wiring, except the only connector was for the three lives - the two neturals were wired directly into the light under the same screw, and the single live was wired directly in

Comment: Is the light fixture controlled by a wall switch or a pull chain?

Comment: I just realized this is in the UK, right? So that is why I don't understand the wiring. My brother is an electrical engineer (US trained) who has had some experience with UK power systems. He tells me that UK systems are different and in important ways better than ours in the US. He has told me that the US, being the original world leader in electrification, standardized before Europe which then got the benefit of seeing the results of some of our choices which were sub-optimal.

Comment: @JimStewart True.  In this case he is dealing with a standard ceiling rose (well that's what he linked anyway) -- this 3/3/2 arrangement elegantly handles 1) supply 2) switch 3) lamp proper and d) something downstream: either a) always-hot to something else, or b) a switched lamp also on this switch.  The hot and neutral going downstream go on the 3-void splices, the rest is hooked up depending on a) or b).

Comment: @Harper, so in the UK the incoming power cable always goes into the ceiling box ('ceiling rose') so there is always a cable switch loop with hot and switched hot , and there may be a 3rd cable that goes on to power other devices.  And this ceiling rose has connector blocks with screw connections to make all the necessary connections as opposed to the US system where the ceiling box is just an empty box and the connections are made on site with approved connectors (usually twist on wire nuts, but now could be WAGO or AlumiConn). The US system connection system takes more space and . .

Comment: . . . has more potential for mistakes. Also the ceiling rose enforces standardization of connections so one does not have to do much tracing and figuring to determine if it is correctly wired. The ceiling rose is presumably thin like a 1/2" deep US 'pancake' box and may be surface mounted. So no cavity would be required for a ceiling rose.

Comment: This is from the UK - unfortunately the fitting doesn't have a proper rose, just the 2 backstabs, although the diagram I linked does show all the wires I had and connections that were required. I did as @Harper suggested and bought some additional flex to feed down to the fitting, then used wago connectors up in the loft to make all the connections shown in the diagram